# How do I write instructions inside map in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda, partial, functools

The input is a list: ["asdf", "ghjk", "lmnop", "zyx"].

I specifically need to apply a function over all elements of the list (so, I should use map). The function should do something like f(x, k) = x + k, where k is a constant equal to 1, and x is a counter (hence, x will be 0 at first, and when gradually iterating over the list, it should increment somehow, but how?).

Assuming these, the expected output should be: [1, 2, 3, 4].

```
from functools import partial


def f(x, k):
    return x + k


def with_partial(my_list, k=1):
    func = partial(f, k=k)  # partial object which acts as a function when called
    x = 0  # counter

    # map -> applies a funciton over all elements of my_list
    rez = list(map(lambda it: (func(x)), my_list))  
    # if I want to increment it, it should look like: rez = list(map(lambda it: x = (func(x)), my_list))
    print("Result with partial: " + str(rez))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    with_partial([5, 6, 7])
    with_partial(["asdf", "ghjk", "lmnop", "zyx"])
```

But the output is:

```
Result with partial: [1, 1, 1]
Result with partial: [1, 1, 1, 1]
```

But I want it to be like:

```
Result with partial: [1, 2, 3]
Result with partial: [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

I can use list comprehension quite easily for that type of problem, but I need to understand how can I write instructions inside map, so that I can increment my counter effectively. Or... Is there anything about partial function I should know already, but I don't? How do I solve this type of problem using functional programming?

Comment: Weird that it executed at all as `lambda it: (func(x))` should throw an error. Btw, such a function already exists, check `enumerate()`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it does work pretty well. My concern right now is: what if I need to map only the given list, without using enumerate on it or modifying it?